# how to prevent vertical overflow but allow horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css

i am trying to zoom images and have tiny images at the bottom of the zoomed image which users can click to zoom. the zooming is done right but the tiny images does not overflow the way it should. i want the images in the div(other_media) to avoid a vertical overflow but allow a horizontal overflow so that users can scroll only left and right.
this is the html and css for the tiny images

```
#listing{
    float:left;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    margin:2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
}
<div id="other_media">
   while($ots = mysql_fetch_array($other)){ ?>
      <div id="listing">
         <img src="<?php echo $paths; ?>" id="<?php echo $ots['class']; ?>" />
      </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the php stuff,it's not relevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Just set:

```
#listing {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    ...
}
```

EDIT: Look at TylerKendrick's answer, it is more correct than mine.

Comment: Because of his setup, this response isn't exactly correct.  `overflow-x` on `#other_media` should be set to `scroll` instead.

Comment: Almost there ;)
 His `#listing` div is actually the div with `float:left;` applied.  This means that applying scroll to `overflow-x` will not achieve the desired effect. (Horizontal scroll display of divs with images)  He needs to apply `overflow-x:scroll;` to the `#other_media` element as noted in my answer down below.

Comment: I just upvoted your answer instead of editing mine; you deserve the rep anyway haha!

Comment: it does not work. The horizontal scroll bar appears alright but the overflowed content other other_media element still goes vertical making the scroll bar useless

Comment: Did you make the changes in my comment down below?  I changed your `id="listing"` attribute to read `class="listing"`; Removed `float:left;` and added `display: inline-block;` to the class listing css.

Answer (score 3):

If you want literal vertical overflow to be hidden:

`overflow-x: scroll;`
`overflow-y: hidden;`

Otherwise:

```
#other_media {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.listing{
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    margin:2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3); 
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    display:inline-block;
}
<div id="other_media">
   while($ots = mysql_fetch_array($other)){ ?>
      <div class="listing">
         <img src="<?php echo $paths; ?>" id="<?php echo $ots['class']; ?>" />
      </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with overflow-x and overflow-x?

```
overflow-x:visible;
overflow-y:hidden;
```